# Protecting ECDH against MITM attacks

Tags: security, diffie-hellman

I am working on a project that requires an ECDH key exchange. I am trying to understand how to protect against MITM attacks. I can sign the public key and send a signature along with the public key transfer to ensure that the key has not been tampered with but that doesn't stop a MITM attack from just doing the same thing. I understand that the key exchange must be verified somehow by a third party but I'm having a hard time understanding how it is that a third party can be the solution assuming that someone can do an MITM attack. Why couldn't they just do an MITM on the third party verification too? Is there really a fail proof way of completely eliminating all possible MITM attacks without some kind of pre-known by both parties?

Answer (score 1):

You need a¹ **trusted** third party to sign both keys.

Without *any* knowledge or assertions about the identity of the intended partner, there's simply no way to distinguish him² from anyone else.

<sup>¹ one or multiple</sup>
<sup>² Bob</sup>

Comment: Right, but why couldn't there be a MITM going between the third party signing process?

Comment: @hobeau Well, you need some out-of-band mechanism to create trust in the first place, whether it's between the trustee Trent and Bob or between Alice and Bob. There's no way to derive identities (or trust) form nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In a PKI system, "certifying authorities" are an important part of the infrastructure. Certifying authorities sign the public key and the identifying information, so that you know the corresponding private really belongs to the purported identity. This is true for EC keys just as it is for RSA.

By the way, [I've looked for CAs that issue EC certificates,](https://serverfault.com/questions/91212/do-any-well-known-cas-issue-elliptic-curve-certificates) and apparently they aren't in practical use.

Most people obtain certificates for their certifying authorities as part of their operating system or security application. They trust these certificates implicitly. There are several dangers here, though.

First, most users don't have an effective way to verify the integrity of these certificates. This is a pretty hard problem, because, at the root of it, you have to have a 100% trustworthy channel for the verification—channel between the authority and the user with which an attacker cannot tamper. When a user downloads a new browser with an collection of root certificates, he can't know that the software wasn't tampered with in transit, or even built with a bogus CA certificate in the collection.

Even if the certificate collection is received intact as the provider intended, there have been questions raised about the integrity of many certifying authorities included by default in popular software. For example, some have pointed out that telecommunications companies in states that have been linked to terror sponsorship have their certificates included in popular browsers. Any trusted authority can issue a certificate for any domain name, and a browser will accept it without question.

In short, no, there is *no way* to establish a secure channel without first sharing some information on a secure channel. The benefit of PKI and asymmetric cryptography is that *one* exchange on a secure channel (the receipt of a trusted authority's certificate) permits the establishment of secure channels with *many* parties. But you have to bootstrap the system somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are heading down a path of rolling your own crypto protocol.  Don't do that.  It's a bad idea.  It leads to insecure systems.

Instead, use SSL or TLS.  That is designed to take care of the subtle issues in designing this kind of crypto protocol -- and it has been well-vetted.  You'll need a way to verify the other endpoint's certificate.  You could use a certification authority, or in some cases it might be feasible to hardcode the public key of the entity you expect to talk to.

You may get better answers if you ask on the [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Bear in mind that many vulnerabilities in versions of SSL and TLS have been found in the past, and that there may be more in them we don't know about.